# Llamar a un snackbar desde un menu de botones

Tags: android-studio

Tengo un menu creado de 3 botones y un metodo llmar item entonces necesito que al pulsar un boton me salga un snackbar con los datos que he recogido. 
Mi idea es crear un String donde vuelco con get todos lo datos y ese string se lo paso al snak bar no si se se puede.
Mi problema principal es llamar al snakbar desde los Uri y que pasar al snackbar
Este es mi codigo

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText et1, et2, et3, et4, et5;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        et1 = findViewById(R.id.et1);
        et2 = findViewById(R.id.et2);
        et3 = findViewById(R.id.et3);
        et4 = findViewById(R.id.et4);
        et5 = findViewById(R.id.et5);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void llamarIntent(View vista) {
        Intent intent = null;
        switch (vista.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                   intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse());
            Snackbar.make(tv1,   ,Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true:
```

}
en el intent uripase debo de pasarle algo que no se como pasarle el snackbar
y en el espacio del snackbar no se si ponerme un String mensaje donde aparte importe todo los datos de et1 et2 et3 etc

Comment: La vista tv1 no esta siendo creada.

Comment: eso es lo de menos ya esta creada pero vamos me falta la integracion de una cosa en la otra

Comment: Ok, entonces solo pegaste código como ejemplo. "llamar al snakbar desde los Uri" no se puede

Comment: Es el codigo que yo cree pero no se como unir las 2 cosas